# How to disable google "bird's eye" view in OpenLayers?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, openlayers

I'm using Openlayers and "google satellite" as base layer. From a certain zoom level, the image switches to the oblique view, named "bird's eye" view and proposed by google. I'd like to know how to disable it and still have a vertical view

Currently, I've just limited the zoom level. But this solution doesn't suit me in the long term.
(Important to notice : I just want to use the "google satellite" layer)

Definition of my base layer :

```
 gsat :  new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
            "google satellite",
            {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,'sphericalMercator' : true}
 ),
```

Best regards,

Ugo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you will have to poke at the underlying GMap object directly - something like this should do it I think:

```
layer.mapObject.setTilt(0)
```

The weird thing is that my reading of the Google docs says that you have to explicitly turn it on if you want it, and OpenLayers isn't doing that, but still seems to get it.